# Chrome mis-judges screen size

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, sass

I'm just trying out responsive design for the first time so I'm not sure if I did something, but I think it's just a bug.

Right now if I shift part of the browser off screen and expand it out to about 1345 it clicks into the css that I have set for 1224

```
//So this and @media all are the only ones which work currently
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
//  div { border: 3px solid purple;}
}
// all others do nothing, confirmed via trial and error
// Works at 1346
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {

  @import "layouts/laptop/layout";
  @include header-large(1224);
  @include logo-mixin;
  @include nav-large(1224);
  @include registrar-mixin;
  @include presenter-mixin(1224);
  @import "bodies/laptop/body";
  @include index-detail-mixin;
  @include show-mixins;
  @include object-location;
}
```

I'm on a Mac OS Mav and everything works as expected in Safari, FF, and Chrome Canary. And to be honest Chrome was acting weird ever since I added jQuery UI. Like JS wouldn't run if the dev tools is open for a while, although that seems to be solved now after a round with `jshint` and some added semicolons. So, I guess that was my fault but again FF and Safari didn't blink. Oh, I've also tried disabling all my extensions and reloading the page, but that didn't work either. So, I'm about at the end of my very limited CSS knowledge.

EDIT: I should also mention this just happened a couple of days ago. It was working fine before this. I just woke up one morning and the css stopped working.

Comment: I assume you're using SASS, since that's not valid vanilla CSS?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add the tag. But it doesn't seem to be that issue, and it's a rails app. But the styling seems to be fine, it's the @media calls, which I just copy and pasted from css-tricks.com

Comment: You're using min-width: 1224px, and 1345 is greater than 1224, so why wouldn't it be applying that CSS at 1345 px? I'm not really clear on what the actual issue you're experiencing is.

Comment: "You're using min-width: 1224px, and 1345 is greater than 1224, so why wouldn't it be applying that CSS at 1345 px?" Yes, that's my question too, literally.

Comment: So it's NOT applying the CSS? Because you said "I shift part of the browser off screen and expand it out to about 1345 it clicks into the css that I have set for 1224". Are you saying that it doesn't apply it at 1224 but waits until 1345? Because I'm not clear why you're specifically mentioning 1345 px, otherwise. EDIT: I think I get it. Sorry I found it so confusing.

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought that was clear. I have the browser expanded to the width of my screen (or on full screen same deal) on my MacBook Pro and the only css which shows is the one for min-width 320. Now, if I shift the browser half off screen, and start expanding it at about 1345 (using the counter that shows up when you have dev tools open) the CSS that's set for 1224 activates, or clicks or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: You know I had a similar problem once on a coworkers machine.  A page I was working on kept displaying with the wrong media query on his computer.  Drove me nuts for a couple hours until we smacked ourselves in the forehead and he realized that he had accidentally hit Ctrl++ and zoomed in slightly.  Perhaps not your problem but worth double checking.

Comment: @dcc put that as an answer and I'll accept it because that did it. Jeez, I didn't even see the magnifying glass in the url bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound stupid but is an easily overlooked problem that caused me hours of frustration and embarrassment.

Double check that your browser is not zoomed at all and you are viewing the page at default 100% zoom level.

If you zoom in or out in the browser it will affect media queries and they will not display correctly.

[image]